# How to like object on index view with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have object that user can like in rails app. It works fine. But I'm trying to add ajax functionality to the like button so when I click it, it updates automatically.

It works on the first object in the index list, but the others do not update via ajax.

I assume this has something to do with the fact that I'm using classes. How would I go about potentially changing this to use ID's to ensure all objects can be updated each. I've tried using ID's but I'm not doing something right here. Any thoughts?

Here's my vote.js.erb file

```
    <% if current_user.liked? @candidate %>
         $('.like-btn').removeClass('liked');
     <% else %> 
         $('.like-btn').addClass('liked');
    <% end %>  
        $('.likes-count').html("<%= @candidate.get_upvotes.size %>")
```

And here is my view

```
       <%= link_to like_candidate_path(candidate), class: "like-btn", method: 
       :put, remote: :true do %> 
       <div>
           <span><p><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></p></span>
       </div>
       <% end %> 
       <span class="likes-count"><%= candidate.get_upvotes.size %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view,

```
<%= link_to like_candidate_path(candidate), class: "like-btn",id:"like_button_#{candidate.id}" method: 
       :put, remote: :true do %> 
<span class="likes-count" id="likes_count#{candidate.id}"><%= candidate.get_upvotes.size %></span>
```

In your controller,

```
def vote
   #Your code to udpate here
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
end
```

In your vote.js.erb

```
<% if current_user.liked? @candidate %>
  $('#like_button_<%=@candiate.id%>').removeClass('liked');
<% else %> 
  $('#like_button_<%=@candiate.id%>').addClass('liked');
<% end %>  
$('#like_count_<%=@candiate.id%>').html("<%= @candidate.get_upvotes.size %>")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for some reason that's not working. Record is updating, but it's not refreshing via ajax. It's important to note, I had to fix a few of your @candiate spelling to be correct, and then also I fixed likes_count to be like_count and that still didn't do the trick :(